# Function to scan list of arrays for a character and return all arrays that contain it

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a function that will scan all arrays for a character and return all arrays that contain that character. For example, how do i check if the first string in an array ends with "_"?

```
Example: searchNames([ [ "marco", "marco@polo.com" ], [ "john_", "john@doe.com" ] ]);

//should output [ [ "john_", "john@doe.com" ] ]
```

This is what I've done so far: http://jsfiddle.net/marcusdei/ve57p28h/

For those who prefer to see my code here:

```
function searchNames(logins){
 var str = "_";
 for (var i = 0; i != logins.length; i++) {
     var substring = logins[i];
     if (str.indexOf(substring) != - 1) {
         return substring;
        }
    }
        return null; 
}
```

Comment: //should output [ [ "john_", "john@doe.com" ] ] - You mean the output should be this?

Comment: Yes you're right! Correction.

Comment: Your code should be in your question, not only in an external link.

Comment: The code is now included in the question

Comment: Thanks all for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying JavaScript filter will do the job :

```
[ [ "marco", "marco@polo.com" ], [ "john_", "john@doe.com" ] ].filter(
    function(data){ 
    return data[0]?data[0].lastIndexOf('_')==data[0].length-1:false;
});
```

Comment: Note that your function does not filter out the empty string

Comment: Also, `john_x_` will be filtered out, while it does end with `_`

Comment: This worked for me. One of the hardest assignments I've ever worked on. Thanks!

Comment: This still doesn't work for `'john _x _'`, it will be filtered out

Comment: It works for `john_x_` .

`[ [ "marco", "marco@polo.com" ], [ "john_x_", "john@doe.com" ] ].filter(
    function(data){ 
    return data[0]?data[0].lastIndexOf('_')==data[0].length-1:false;
});`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a classic use case for array's [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var input=[ [ "marco", "marco@polo.com" ], [ "john_", "john@doe.com" ] ];
var output=input.filter( function (x) {
//if want to see whether a '_' is found in the string
return x[0].indexOf('_')>-1;
//Or, only at the last position
//return x[0].length>0 ? x[0][x[0].length-1] == '_' : false;

} );
```

Comment: I didn't see at first that the OP wanted only the last char to be `_`, I've edited my answer

Comment: @rainbowloops I've added the two options, use whatever suits your needs

Comment: use the second one if want to filter only those who end with `_`, and why would you expect to see `["barfoot","bar_foo@fb.com"‌​]` ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a function called [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Here's a clean, functional approach.

```
function hasUnderscore (string) {
  return string.substr(-1) == '_' ? true : false
}

function doWithNthGetter (nth, func) {
  return function (array) {
    return func(array[nth])
  }
}

var checkThis = [ [ "marco", "marco@polo.com" ], [ "john_", "john@doe.com" ] ]

checkThis.filter(nthGetter(2, hasUnderscore))
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked your code little bit. if you are looking for string ending with '_'

```
function searchNames(logins){
 var str = "_";
 var newArray=[];   
 for (var i = 0; i < logins.length; i++) {
     var substring = logins[i][0];
     if (substring[substring.length-1]==str) {
         newArray.push( logins[i]);
        }
    }
        return newArray; 
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ve57p28h/2/)

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/b1afw9zu/)***

I would suggest creating a special function to call for this scenario where you can filter based on a callback compare function.

```
function searchArray(arr2d,compare){
 return arr2d.filter(function(arr){
  return compare(arr);
 });
}
```

Once that is in place, you can take your input

```
var input = [ [ "marco", "marco@polo.com" ], [ "john_", "john@doe.com" ] ];
```

And then call the search with the input and a callback

```
var result = searchArray(input,function(arr){ 
    var s = arr[0];//check that the first string
    return s[s.length-1] == "_";//ends in _
});//this callback function can be modified if the conditions change
```

---

*stacksnippet*

```js
function searchArray(arr2d,compare){
 return arr2d.filter(function(arr){
    return compare(arr);
 });
}

var input = [ [ "marco", "marco@polo.com" ], [ "john_", "john@doe.com" ] ];

var result = searchArray(input,function(arr){ 
    var s = arr[0];
    return s[s.length-1] == "_";
});

console.log(result);
document.getElementById('choice').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<div id="choice"></div>
```